# Cannot Find Symbol, Symbol : Method setDate(Date) in Netbeans

Tags: java, date, netbeans, compiler-errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeHIW.png)

I'm getting an error Cannot Find Symbol, Symbol : Method setDate(Date).

This is my import code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import sun.applet.Main;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
```

and here is the code that have an error (line 6) :

```
private String idTransaksi() {
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String tanggal = sdf.format(date);
            txtDate.setDate(date);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String tanggal2 = sdf2.format(date);
            String qDate = "SELECT time, sellID FROM mssell";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(qDate);
            idJual = "Trans." + tanggal2;

            String query = "INSERT INTO t_jual VALUES ('"+idJual+"','"+tanggal+"','ADMIN',0,0,'NOTHING')";
            stm.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
        return idJual;
    }
```

What am i missing ? Any helping answer appreciated.

Comment: What is `txtDate`? Where have you declared it?

Comment: Please add txtDate declaration.

Comment: that is the my TextField name. I confused what to use between setText and setDate because both of them bring an error.

Comment: any help please ? Or i should change that textfield ?

Comment: According to joined image at line 111, you have to put (tanggal) txtDate.setText(tanggal);

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` since those classes are long outdated and poorly designed. Instead I suggest `Instant` and `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You should also consider a parameterized SQL statements with `?` placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code ;

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
String tanggal = sdf.format(date);  //this tanggal for what? use this !!
txtDate.setDate(date); // date should be the string type. so make this tanggal and setText
```

So final code should be like ;

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
String tanggal = sdf.format(date);
txtDate.setText(tanggal);
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

FYI, you are using *terrible* old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-23

For database access, use JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).